# Preview a file in Mac OS X (Mavericks)

Tags: macos, text

The files i would like to preview are text files but the filename is not ending as .txt, but the extensions are different. For example .obj or .pol.

Comment: It is not clear whether you are asking a programming question or a user question.

Comment: It is a user question, but I'm assuming that needs probably some coding to be happened.

Comment: What do you mean by "preview"?  Use the "Quick Look" function of the Mac OS, or open in the Preview app, or something else?

Comment: Right! Since there is a preview.app I have probably confused you. No, i don't mean the app but the preview in finder or as you sent, "Quick look".

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specific which language you are using, so assuming you are using Swift 1.2 and you are loading a text file called `myfile.obj` in UTF-8:

```
var error: NSError?
if let preview = String(contentsOfFile: "myfile.obj", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &error) {
    println("File preview: " + preview)
}

if error != nil {
    println("Error: " + error!.localizedDescription)
}
```

You could also use `contentsOfURL:` if you prefer `NSURL`.